# Create a VM using KVM with an IP address to ssh

Tags: 14.04, kvm-virtualization, virtualization

How do I create a VM using KVM and assign an IP address so that I can SSH into the machine and install the stuff I need?

I'm using KVM on a Ubuntu server edition and hence would like to know how to work from the terminal.

The server I'm acccessing has a static IP.